# Using broom::tidy on felm result with clustered standard errors

Tags: r, broom, lfe

I'm trying to extract point estimates and confidence intervals from a panel data model. The following reproduces the error using the canned example from the `lfe` documentation. The only small change I've made is to cluster standard errors at the firm-level to replicate my issue in `est2`.

```
## create covariates
x <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(length(x))

## individual and firm
id <- factor(sample(20,length(x),replace=TRUE))
firm <- factor(sample(13,length(x),replace=TRUE))

## effects for them
id.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(id))
firm.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(firm))

## left hand side
u <- rnorm(length(x))
y <- x + 0.5*x2 + id.eff[id] + firm.eff[firm] + u

## estimate and print result
est1 <- felm(y ~ x+x2| id + firm)
summary(est1)

## estimate and print result with clustered std errors
est2 <- felm(y ~ x+x2| id + firm | 0 | firm)
summary(est2)
```

I can tidy in the non-clustered SE version or *without* including the fixed effects:

```
tidy(est1)
tidy(est2)
tidy(est1, fe = TRUE)
```

But I can't if I ask for the fixed effects:

```
tidy(est2, fe = TRUE)
```

The error is this: `Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'se' not found`

I'm not sure if this is a `broom` side problem or an `lfe` side problem. It is possible I'm doing something wrong, but there should be point estimates and standard errors for the fixed effects whether or not I cluster the SEs. (And the fact that there are fewer clusters than FEs is probably an econometric issue, but it doesn't seem to be driving this particular problem.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `lfe::getfe()` is supposed to return the columns `c('effect','se','obs','comp','fe','idx')` according to its help page. However, if you run

`lfe::getfe(est1, se = TRUE)` and

`lfe::getfe(est2, se = TRUE)`

in the second instance, the standard errors are in a column named `clusterse` instead of `se`.

The error message is a result of the function `broom:::tidy.felm` using `lfe::getfe()` and then `dplyr::select(se)`.

I guess technically it's an `lfe` problem but I'm not sure which package will be easier to amend

Update: I emailed Simen Gaure (the package author) and he'll be releasing to CRAN some time this spring